# Wordpress database didn't update

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been used following code to create extra field able to show sales representative related to each customer when the customer registration. but i couldn't update or change the data base. Please help
the Code is...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
<h3>Extra profile information</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
    <td>Sales Rep</td>
    <td><select  class="ui search dropdown"  name="Sales_Rep" >
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Mr.ABC">Mr.ABC</option>
            <option value="Mr.DEF">Mr.DEF</option>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
        </script>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').addClass('regular-text');
    $('select[name=Sales_Rep]').val('<?php echo get_the_author_meta('Sales_Rep', $user->ID); ?>');
</script>
}
<?php 
function new_modify_user_table_xdt( $column ) {
$column['Sales_Rep'] = 'Sales Rep';
return $column; }

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table_xdt' );
function new_modify_user_table_row_xdt( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
$meta = get_user_meta($user_id);
switch ($column_name) {
    case 'Sales_Rep' :
        $Sales_Rep = $meta['Sales_Rep'][0];
        return $Sales_Rep;
    default:
}
return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row_xdt', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: What error do you get? Have you try some debug?

Comment: no any errors. code was right.  the issue is can't update customers sales rep.